# Compiler requests storage keyword which produces the next compiler error

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, storage, struct

I want to deploy a contract via Mist, but the compiler tells me to use the *storage* keyword:
[image]

I tried many things including this one:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

//listing 1
contract Trace{

struct Tru{
    bool consumed;
    bool used;
    bool created;
    uint id;
    uint producedBy;
    uint consumedBy;
}

struct PrimitiveActivity{
    bool created;
    string storage name;
    uint id;
    uint inputTruId;
    uint outputTruId;
}
}
```

However this just produces the next compiler error:

*Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity'
        string storage name;
               ^*

Has anyone an idea how I can resolve this issue? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using compiler version 4.14 (specifically 0.4.14+commit.c2215d46). The issue about needing the "storage" keyword goes away.  You can select the compiler version in Remix on the settings tab.